# Problem drawing more than one texture in WebGL

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl

I'm developing a little exercise in WebGL to start learning, which consists on loading simple geometry with textures. However, I'm a bit stuck with a little problem I'm having on rendering meshes with textures.

The point is that I have a main code which loads 2 triangles and 2 squares and generates a texture for one of the triangles, and all that renders perfectly.

[image: One Texture Rendering]

However, if I try to load more textures, all the textured objects except the one with the last texture loaded, are not rendered.

[image: like this].

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, since it works a bit different than OpenGL. I looked at the code again and I don't get it. The code to render each object is the next step (a bit hardcoded, but is just to learn WebGL), which just binds a buffer with `Position` and `TextureCoordinates` attributes, sends some uniforms and draws:

```
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh.getID());
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader_bound.vPosAttr, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 0);        
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shader_bound.vTCoordAttr, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 20, 12);

        shader_bound.SetUniformMat4f("u_ModelMatrix", mesh.getModelMatrix());
        shader_bound.SetUniformVec4f("u_Color", mesh.getMeshColor());   
        shader_bound.SetUniform1i("u_UseTextures", 0);

        if(mesh.getMeshTexture() != null)
        {
            gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, mesh.getMeshTexture().getTexture());
            shader_bound.SetUniform1i("u_AlbedoTexture", 0);
            shader_bound.SetUniform1i("u_UseTextures", 1);
        }

        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, mesh.getVertexNumber());
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

The shader is very basic, the only thing it does is to determine if it has texture or not (with the "u_UseTextures" uniform), and, based on that, paints the mesh with color or with texture*color.

Does anybody see where the error is? Thanks!

**Edit:** I added a log just after activating and binding the texture in the code I show. The log just shows the name of the texture that's being bounded and it seems it's correct:

[image: Console Logs]

Comment: There is no obvious error in the code you posted in the question. Maybe post more code? I assume you waited for the textures to load? You could go to each texture and give them names like `tex1.myName = 'tex1'; tex2.myName = 'tex2';` Then add some `console.log` lines to print the textures being used `tex = mes.getMeshTexture().getTexture(); console.log('tex:', tex.myName);` etc...  Another question is are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Sure, I'm guessing that the loading of textures is correct since otherwise nothing would be seen... About the name & log, is a good idea, I'll edit the question to post another image so you can see it... But there is no apparent mistake. In the console, there is no error, so I assume is something about WebGL (graphical?) since it gives no errors

Comment: Well then next up. Draw the same texture on all shapes. check your texture coordinates. In fact draw them in the shader, add `gl_FragColor = vec4(fract(whateverYourTextureCoordinatesAreNamed), 0, 1)`; You should get a red/green gradient across your shape. FYI, We're actually supposed to vote to close your question because you haven't put enough code in your question for us to be able to answer.

Comment: Well, using the same textures in all the objects renders all properly! The thing on the UVs I've already tried it, and they are correct, so that's why I didn't mentioned... About the code, I also think is few code, but I don't really know what other code to put, since that's the most directly related (I mean, I could put the shader but it's the most simple and basic line, and if it wasn't working, it should not even render anything textured, right?)... Pretty lost on that terms...

Comment: And the same with all... I could put the loading textures code, but it should not load any texture if it wasn't working

Comment: It's is not that that hard to make a small WebGL sample that repos your issue. [Here's one](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/09hbdrvy/) that uses your code that shows the code you posted works just fine. It would easily fit in a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: You might find it helpful to use spectorjs to inspect what textures/buffers are actually bound when you draw: https://spector.babylonjs.com/